# Xamarin App Crashes When Using Custom Text Styles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, crash

I am creating a cross-platform Android & iOS app with Xamarin. I am trying to add custom styles for labels to my AppShell.xaml page so I can use those styles on other pages. When I try to use those styles using `{StaticResource BodyText}` or `{StaticResource HeaderText}` (following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/styles) documentation), the app crashes with a very generic error. When I remove the reference to the styles, the app runs fine. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can effectively create my own label styles to use on other pages?

AppShell.xaml code:

```
<Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkPink}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkGreen}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            
            <Style x:Key="BodyText" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="HeaderText" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
            </Style>

</Shell>
```

WelcomePage.xaml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KnittingApp.Views.WelcomePage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KnittingApp.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="welcome.jpg"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource HeaderText}" Text="Welcome to KnittingApp"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource BodyText}" Text="This is my text."/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Relevant section of debug output:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
...
...
...
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 11 (of 12) of /data/data/com.companyname.knittingapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 11 of /data/data/com.companyname.knittingapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment[0xec40f800] -> Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager[0xec410c40]: 3
[Mono] Requesting loading reference 12 (of 15) of /data/data/com.companyname.knittingapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll
[Mono] Loading reference 12 of /data/data/com.companyname.knittingapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Google.Android.Material[0xebeb0420] -> Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager[0xec410c40]: 4
[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Comment: I would need to see more code here and a full repro as adding this code into a new project works just fine. It looks like it is something else with your app, do you have it somewhere to look at?

Comment: @JamesMontemagno, I have added the error-causing code back to my app and pushed to [GitHub.](https://github.com/ekelly1995/KnittingApp). I'm still not sure what the issue is, but I am hoping it is something simple that I am overlooking. Any help you can offer is appreciated!

Comment: Your project seems to be missing the ViewModel folder.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT You were correct. I started with an app template and deleted things before I knew what they were. I am going to properly rebuild the structure of my application to make sure things work as they should.